# Running protractor test parallel on different environments

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I would like to run my protractor test on different environments such as

```
testing it on local environment, 
testing it on test environment,
testing it on production
```

environment and so on at the same time and using the same browser example chrome.

So in this case my base URL would change for every environment: When I run the test I would like to run it parallel on all the different environments.

```
baseUrl:'localhost:8080'
baseUrl:'tst.company.com'
baseUrl:'prod.company.com'
etc
```

and browser remains the same

```
multiCapabilities:[
{ 'browsername':'chrome',
  'chromeOptions':{
      'binary': 'drive:pathToChrome',
      'args':'[]'
      'extensions':[]
    }
}]
```

Any one knows how to, on this cases.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this with a *task manager*: `grunt` and [`grunt-parallel`](https://github.com/iammerrick/grunt-parallel).

Create 3 separate grunt task configurations with different `baseUrl` settings (you would need [`grunt-protractor-runner`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-runner) package installed).

Comment: Will try this, but is there any way to specify the same in the conf.js file of protractor.

Comment: @patz cannot recall anything like this in protractor. I'm pretty sure you cannot solve it with `protractor` only. Would be happy to be wrong though.